# How do I render new Twitter widget dynamically?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter

If I register a widget on Twitter, I get the following code:

```
<a class="twitter-timeline" href="https://twitter.com/vinto60utd" data-widget-id="283564783750483968">Tweets by @vinto60utd</a>
<script>!function(d,s,id){var js,fjs=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];if(!d.getElementById(id))>>>{js=d.createElement(s);js.id=id;js.src="//platform.twitter.com/widgets.js";fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js,fjs);}}>(document,"script","twitter-wjs");</script>
```

If I put this code as it is on my page, I see the Twitter widget as I wanted. How do I render my widgets dynamically or on the execution of some event (like button click)?

Comment: Did you add some > and >>> to the code?

Comment: yeah I did to put that code in a block ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change

```
!function(d,s,id){var js,fjs=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];if(!d.getElementById(id)){js=d.createElement(s);js.id=id;js.src="//platform.twitter.com/widgets.js";fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js,fjs);}}(document,"script","twitter-wjs");
```

To

```
function twit(d,s,id){var js,fjs=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];if(!d.getElementById(id)){js=d.createElement(s);js.id=id;js.src="//platform.twitter.com/widgets.js";fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js,fjs);}}
twit(document,"script","twitter-wjs");
```

Comment: <a class="twitter-timeline" href="https://twitter.com/search?q=%23akbarsreign" data-widget-id="293637027746942976">Tweets about "#akbarsreign"</a>
<script>function twit(d,s,id){var js,fjs=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];if(!d.getElementById(id)){js=d.createElement(s);js.id=id;js.src="//platform.twitter.com/widgets.js";fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js,fjs);}}
twit(document,"script","twitter-wjs");</script>

Comment: I want to just change the data widget id dynamically to render different widget registered on my twitter id...but somehow unable to do it?

Comment: I do not understand what you mean

Comment: I have number of widget registered(already created) on my twitter page. I want to show a specific widget for a specific event on my html page.

Comment: Then I suggest iFrames since the code obviously relies on both user name and widget ID

Answer (score 16):

use

```
twttr.widgets.load();
```

if you have loaded //platform.twitter.com/widgets.js already

In my situation I doing like this: replacing content of some empty or previously timeline filled block to new link like yours

```
<a class="twitter-timeline" href="https://twitter.com/vinto60utd" data-widget-id="283564783750483968">
    Tweets by   @vinto60utd</a>
```

then I call     `twttr.widgets.load();` and twitter do the rest.

Comment: Best answer ever! Thank you! :D

Comment: be careful with this as script will search through entire DOM model for elements to change. For sake of better performance use twttr.widgets.load(document.getElementById("YourIDOfElement"));

Answer (score 1):

you can have a single data-widget-id and filter out any tweet message feed by just adding,

```
    data-screen-name="AnyTwitterName"
```

for an example

```
     <a class="twitter-timeline"  data-widget-id="6596840392xxxxxxxx"  data-screen-name="AnyTwitterName" ></a>
```

Answer (score -1):

You can create widgets at run-time using Twitter for Websites JS.

https://dev.twitter.com/web/embedded-timelines