# Twitter embedded for Angular 2

Tags: twitter, angular

I tried to embed Twitter timeline to my Angular 2 app.
I followed this tutorial https://publish.twitter.com 
then I had this

```
<a class="twitter-timeline" href="https://twitter.com/TwitterDev">Tweets by TwitterDev</a> <script async src="//platform.twitter.com/widgets.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
```

I put a tag into template and put script tag into index.html. This is an example.

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Angular 2 App | ng2-webpack</title>
    <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="/img/favicon.ico">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.6.3/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <script async src="//platform.twitter.com/widgets.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
    <base href="/">
  </head>
  <body>
    <my-app>
      <div class="loading-container">
        <div class="loading"></div>
        <div id="loading-text">loading</div>
        <a class="twitter-timeline" href="https://twitter.com/TwitterDev">Tweets by TwitterDev</a>
      </div>
    </my-app>
  </body>
</html>
```

But it only showed the a tag, no timeline.
Please help me !

Comment: Actually it did show up sometimes. I reload the page serveral times and it will show up but not always.

Answer (score 17):

You should run the twitter widget script after your template was loaded.

I did this:

```
export class SectionSocialComponent implements AfterViewInit { 
    constructor() {}

    ngAfterViewInit () {
            !function(d,s,id){
                var js: any,
                    fjs=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],
                    p='https';
                if(!d.getElementById(id)){
                    js=d.createElement(s);
                    js.id=id;
                    js.src=p+"://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js";
                    fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js,fjs);
                }
            }
            (document,"script","twitter-wjs");
    }
}
```

And my .html file only contains this:

```
<a class="twitter-timeline" href="https://twitter.com/TwitterDev">Tweets by TwitterDev</a>
```

Maybe this is not the most elegant solution, but worked for me.

Comment: Hey this solution works but can you please explain what the function inside ngAfterViewInit is doing.

Comment: @AsifKarimBherani It basically insert the twitter widget script asynchronously into your document. You can read more about it here: https://dev.twitter.com/web/javascript/loading I hope it will help You understand, how this works :)

Comment: Hi @ÁbóSzilágyi using that js code now gives an error: error TS1345: An expression of type 'void' cannot be tested for truthiness

Comment: Thanks! your soul has a place in the heavens!! 

Answer (score 16):

Load the Twitter's widgets library on the `index.html` file.

```
<head>
    ....
    <script async src="https://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
</head>
```

Puts the twitter reference on your template

```
<a class="twitter-timeline" href="https://twitter.com/TwitterDev?ref_src=twsrc%5Etfw">Tweets by TwitterDev</a>
```

Declare twitter `var` outside the class of your component as suggested by [springerkc](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3186804/springerkc) on comments.

```
declare var twttr: any;
```

Load the twitter widgets on `AfterViewInit`

```
ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    twttr.widgets.load();
}
```

I know that this is an old question and maybe there this answer out there, but that is the first place that Google send me.

References:
[How do I render new Twitter widget dynamically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14545653/how-do-i-render-new-twitter-widget-dynamically)
[Twitter Developer Documentation](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-for-websites/javascript-api/guides/scripting-loading-and-initialization)

Comment: This is really helpful. I was routing out and again into the component containing twitter embed code. When i was coming back using routing the widget didn't reload. After adding using `twttr.widgets.load();` it worked!

Comment: I have mention you answer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56574072/embedding-twitter-timeline-does-not-render-in-angular-7/56735170#56735170 

Comment: Good solution! If you add `declare var twttr: any;` above the `@Component({})` decorator  of the component you're calling the script in, you can avoid the linting error and don't need to `// @ts-ignore`.

Comment: Hi @springerkc, thanks for sharing this, I edited my answer based on your suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

I have found a rather simple way of achieving this, it works for Angular 6.

Twitter provides with following code. [See here](https://help.twitter.com/en/using-twitter/embed-twitter-feed)

`<a class="twitter-timeline" href="https://twitter.com/TwitterDev/timelines/539487832448843776?ref_src=twsrc%5Etfw">National Park Tweets - Curated tweets by TwitterDev</a> <script async src="https://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js" charset="utf-8"></script>`

It has two tags `<a></a>` and `<script></script>`.

You can place the `<script></script>` tag within the `<head></head>` or `<body></body>` section in the `index.html` of your angular app and `<a></a>` can be placed in the template ( html ) of your desired angular component. It worked like charm.

Answer (score 0):

If you go to [this](https://publish.twitter.com/?url=https%3A%2F%2Ftwitter.com%2FWarcherandson&ref_src=twsrc%5Etfw&ref_url=http%3A%2F%2Fpercy%3A54536%2Fhome%23content#) website, you can enter your twitter URL and it will generate the code for you.

It will provide you with two lines of code.  The second line of code is a script link to a javascript file that twitter is hosting.  It means that we don't need to execute it in the angular world :D

here is an example:

```
<a class="twitter-timeline" href="https://twitter.com/TwitterDev?ref_src=twsrc%5Etfw">Tweets by TwitterDev</a>
<script async src="https://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
```

As Angular strips `script` tags out of its view, you will need to find a workaround.  One workaround is this answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44904601/2069306).

making the example:

```
<a class="twitter-timeline" href="https://twitter.com/TwitterDev?ref_src=twsrc%5Etfw">Tweets by TwitterDev</a>
<script-hack async src="https://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js" charset="utf-8"></script-hack>
```

Answer (score 0):

**you should re-run twitter widgets js file every time routing:**

1. Firstly be sure to import AfterViewInit in your component.

   `import { Component, OnInit, AfterViewInit } from '@angular/core';`
2. Use AfterViewInit in your component class.

   `export class OurNewsComponent implements OnInit, AfterViewInit`
3. Now try this it will be working fine.

```
        ngAfterViewInit() {

        // Tweets
        let ngJs: any;
        const ngFjs = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
        const ngP = 'https';

        if (!document.getElementById('twitter-wjs')) {
          ngJs = document.createElement('script');
          ngJs.id = 'twitter-wjs';
          ngJs.src = ngP + '://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js';
          ngFjs.parentNode.insertBefore(ngJs, ngFjs);

        }
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

Best way to integrate any twitter widgets in Angular2
Use https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-twitter-widgets

Install package

```
npm install --save ngx-twitter-widgets
```

Import NgxTwitterWidgetsModule to NgModule

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgxTwitterWidgetsModule } from "ngx-twitter-widgets";

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    NgxTwitterWidgetsModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Use ngx-twitter-timeline tag to your template

```
<ngx-twitter-timeline
  [source]="{sourceType: 'profile', screenName: 'TwitterDev'}" >
</ngx-twitter-timeline>
```