# twitter embedded and angular

Tags: angular, twitter

i embed twitts on my angular app thanks to [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39455813/twitter-embedded-for-angular-2):

however - i need to update dynamically the twitts, 
i know i need to use the [twttr.widgets.load(),](https://dev.twitter.com/web/javascript/initialization)
but i have no idea how.
also tries [ng2-twitt](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng2-tweet), but could not make it work , and [with this article](http://www.sascha.tech/2016/10/08/angular2-using-the-twitter-javascript-widgets/) cant make twitts to work at all

basically i put the script tag

in the index html and did execly like the thread.
need help to make it work dynamically

My ngAfterViewInit:

```
!function (d, s, id) {
    var js: any,
        fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],
        p = 'https';
    if (!d.getElementById(id)) {
        js = d.createElement(s);
        js.id = id;
        js.src = p + "://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js";
        fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);

    }
```

my html

```
<blockquote class="twitter-tweet"  >
              <a [attr.href]="feed.path"></a>
        </blockquote>
```

Tanks!!