# Embedding twitter timeline does not render in angular 7

Tags: node.js, angular, typescript, ecmascript-6, single-page-application

I am following https://help.twitter.com/en/using-twitter/embed-twitter-feed for embedding timeline in the angular page. Only button renders but not the actual timeline.

The **index.html** looks like:

```
<body style="margin:0">
    <script async src="https://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
    <app-root></app-root>
</body>
```

**app.component.html** looks like below:

```
<a class="twitter-timeline"
   href="https://twitter.com/TwitterDev/lists/national-parks?ref_src=twsrc%5Etfw">
      A Twitter List by TwitterDev
</a>
```

Also tried things like **app.component.ts**:

```
ngOnInit(){
   if ((<any>window).twttr.ready())
      (<any>window).twttr.widgets.load();
}
```

But no luck

Comment: It works if you put it in index.html ?

Comment: yes it does work on putting on index.html

Comment: Just tried it in stackblitz and it seems to be working https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-2mbweb

Comment: yes ur code works in stackblitz but for me it does not. it only works if i put this on index.html. but not in app.components.html

Comment: @MoblizeIT Is there an error in your browser console?

Comment: No error nothing. It would be easier to know otherwise

Comment: Could you share an example reproducting your problem?

Comment: i tried a brand new project and all works there. but it is like a blank angular project. so some package messing up probably. the issue is i dont see any error etc.

Comment: the `widgets.js` must be load after the `twitter-timeline` element is render so the best case is load the script dynamically check my answe  and  the link for the demo  @MoblizeIT

Comment: @yurzui example is working  because the element render before the script has been loaded in my example I create a component for twitter widgets so I must load the script after the component is loaded

Comment: @yurzui check my example https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-twitter-widgets

Comment: I just want to mention there is some angular package for handling embedding twitter timeline check this https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-tweet 

Answer (score 5):

you need to load `widgets.js` script after `twitter-timeline` element is been render so if you place the script in index.html it is will load and the element hasn't render yet.

the best way around it is to create a script tag dynamically after the element is rendered.

*twitter component*

```
export class TwitterComponent  {

  @Input() user:string;

  constructor(private renderer2: Renderer2,private el: ElementRef) {}

  ngAfterViewInit() {

    let scriptEl = document.createElement('script');
    scriptEl.src = "https://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js"

    this.renderer2.appendChild(this.el.nativeElement, scriptEl);

  }

}
```

*template*

```
<a class="twitter-timeline" href="https://twitter.com/{{user}}">Tweets by {{user}}</a>
```

app componenet template

```
<app-twitter [user]="name"></app-twitter>
```

[**angular twitter widgets  ⚡⚡**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-twitter-widgets)

> [ngAfterViewInit](https://angular.io/api/core/AfterViewInit)() a lifecycle hook that is called after Angular has fully initialized a component's view.

**Updated**

a simple soulution mention in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39455813/twitter-embedded-for-angular-2) before by user named Bernardo Baumblatt

put the script link in the `index.html`

```
<script async src="https://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js" charset="utf-8">
</script>
```

load the twitter widgets when ngAfterViewInit method call

```
ngAfterViewInit() {
    // @ts-ignore
    twttr.widgets.load();
  }
```

in any case the script has not loaded yet you will got an error like  `twttr is not defined`  so download the `widgets.js` script and include it to your project by using import

*main.ts*

```
import './app/widgets.js'
```

[**demo**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-twitter-widgets-kjx7op)

Comment: Alternative of widgets import: `(<any>window).twttr.widgets.load();`

Answer (score 2):

I had a requirement of dynamically rendering timelines based on different twitter timelines.

I found a workaround by **creating a variable in the constructor** that stores the href based on the twitter username .

So for example if your link is "https://twitter.com/TwitterDev/lists/national-parks?ref_src=twsrc%5Etfw"
, you just put this in the constructor in a previously defined global variable , say "embedLink"

such as in your ts component:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-tree-dashboard',
  templateUrl: './tree-dashboard.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./tree-dashboard.component.css']
})
export class TreeDashboardComponent implements OnInit,AfterViewInit {
  embedLink='';

  constructor(private matIconRegistry: MatIconRegistry,
              ) {
this.embedLink=  "https://twitter.com/TwitterDev/lists/national-parksref_src=twsrc%5Etfw" 
}};
```

and then in your HTML :

```
<a class="twitter-timeline" href={{embedLink}}></a>
```

And lastly you only need to add the script in index.html which you have done already.
So you're good to go!

Answer (score 1):

Below is my code. I'm creating blank website so I think it's should not be a problem. What I think is maybe the order of the script in index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Twitter</title>
    <base href="/" />

    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <app-root></app-root>
  </body>
  <script
    async
    src="https://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js"
    charset="utf-8"
  ></script>
</html>
```

In my app.component.html

```
<a class="twitter-timeline"
   href="https://twitter.com/TwitterDev/lists/national-parks?ref_src=twsrc%5Etfw">
      A Twitter List by TwitterDev
</a>
```

You can view my code [here](https://github.com/ngohungphuc/Research/tree/master/Angular/twitter)